# If $a$ is a unit then $m - a$ is also a unit RING RESIDUE

Tags: number-theory

Any idea please? I already started my proof but nowhere to go.

Problem: If a $a$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, prove that $m - a$ is also a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Proof: We can say that $a$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ if there exist a number $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 (\mod m)$, that is, $ab - 1 = mx$ or $1 = ab - mx,$ for some integer $x\dots$

Any idea how to proceed would be of great help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ab \equiv 1 \bmod m$, then $(m-a)(m-b) \equiv ab \equiv 1 \bmod m$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $m-a=-a$ in $\Bbb Z_m$. Also, $-1$ is clearly a unit.

Comment: Got it! Tnx a lot sir!!! :)